# Client call on Asynchronous and Synchronous network

Tags: client-server, asynchronous

I was wondering how the client should send a request on server network.

1.) Synchronous client request, Asynchronous network implementation
2.) Synchronous client request, Synchronous network implementation
3.) Asynchronous client request, Asynchronous network implementation
4.) Asynchronous client request, Synchronous network implementation

Out of above 4 implementations, which one is the best implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Synchronous client request, Asynchronous network implementation. Why? Because why not.